# unable to add two date values angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

I have implemented a magnifyChart function where I need to add two time values. But when i do so, it is considering it as a string and concatenating it instead. Eventhough when i perform subtraction on those two values, it gives correct result. How do i get correct result on adding two date values?

```
function magnifyChart (timeA, timeB) {
    var newTimeA;
    var newTimeB;
    var quarterSize = Math.floor((timeB - timeA) / 4);
    logger.info("timeA", timeA); //Fri Sep 08 2017 17:45:19 GMT-0400 (EDT)
    logger.info("timeB", timeB); //Sun Oct 01 2017 16:01:51 GMT-0400 (EDT)
    logger.info("quarterSize", quarterSize); //495248155
    newTimeA = Math.floor(parseInt(timeA) + parseInt(quarterSize));
    newTimeB = Math.floor(timeB - quarterSize);
    logger.info("newTimeA", newTimeA); 
    logger.info("newTimeB", newTimeB);//1506392863689
    return [timeA + quarterSize, timeB - quarterSize];
}
```

Comment: there is no AngularJs in this question, this is javascript date question.

Comment: I just added a function where i am facing an issue. My entire project is done in angular js so if angular date filter can fix this issue then it can be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `date.getTime()` to convert a date to an integer (timestamp). After doing the math, you can convert it back to a date by doing `new Date(integer)`.

Comment: Yes it worked perfectly on doing date.getTime() and then converting back to Date string. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If *timeA* and *timeB* are Date objects, then in:

```
newTimeA = Math.floor(parseInt(timeA) + parseInt(quarterSize));
```

the expression `parseInt(timeA)` will coerce *timeA* to string first, then attempt to parse it to number, which might return a number or *NaN*.

To fix that, the simplest way is to use [unary + operator](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-unary-plus-operator):

```
newTimeA = +timeA + quarterSize;
```

There is no need for *Math.floor* since both values are already integers and adding them must produce another integer.

The expression `+timeA` will return its time value, which is specified to be an integer (or NaN, but *Math.floor* won't fix that) and *quarterSize* must be an integer from *Math.floor* in:

```
var quarterSize = Math.floor((timeB - timeA) / 4);
```

When you subtract two dates, the `-` operator coerces both to number first, so `timeB - timeA` "works" without any special treatment.

You generate *newTimeA* and *newTimeB* but don't use them for anything, so I presume they're for debug only.

So your code reduces to:

```
function magnifyChart (timeA, timeB) {
    var quarterSize = Math.floor((timeB - timeA) / 4);
    return [+timeA + quarterSize, +timeB - quarterSize];
}
```

If you want to return Dates instead of time values, do:

```
    return [new Date(+timeA + quarterSize),
            new Date(+timeB - quarterSize)];
```

**NB**
In the case of `+timeB - quarterSize`, unary `+` isn't required since subtraction will coerce the Date to a number anyway, however it's likely useful for maintenance to keep the code consistent.

Comment: Hey thanks! I didnt know +timeA return its time value. I got to learn something new. And it works fine :)